My Django website is unable to know if visitor is logged in or not
I am trying to deploy a website which does something depending on if the user is login or not. I tested it on local host and it worked but now that I try to deploy on pythonanywhere it seems to to recognize user though I logged in again. I used the "user.is_authenticated method" in my html template

kindly provide exact details of the issue. your login is not working ?. did you got any error message ?. please share these details along with settings.py file for better understanding of issue.

you provide no infomation about what you want, what you did, what you code.
in template:
user.is_authenticated => if user logined True, else False
user.is_anonymous => if user loinged False, else True

in views.py
request.user.is_authenticated => if user logined True, else False
request.user.is_anonymous => if user loinged False, else True


I have found my mistake

i did not use Login() i only used create user
def sign_in(request):
    form=Utilisateur(request.GET)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=Utilisateur(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data["username"],
                                     password=form.cleaned_data["password"],
                                     first_name=form.cleaned_data["first_name"],
                                     last_name=form.cleaned_data["last_name"],
                                     email=form.cleaned_data["email"]
                                     )
            user=authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data["username"],password=form.cleaned_data["password"])
            login(request,user)
            UserProfile.objects.create(username=form.cleaned_data["username"],profile_img=form.cleaned_data["profile_img"])
            return redirect("home")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("UNE ERREUR EST SURVENUE LORS DE VOTRE INSCRIPTION REESSAYEZ")
    context={"form":form}
    return render(request,'signin.html',context)```


now that i added it, it works. It was difficult for me to notice these things since i was on local host at first
